# How to delete Tomcat and Play logs after n days in linux operating system?

Tags: logging, playframework, tomcat8

I want to delete all log files in tomcat after n days. I have been trying on this by different ways. Nothing is worked for me, may be i was missed something. Please help me on how can I delete tomcat log files and play logs without script running, For all help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For PlayFramework, in your logging configuration file (`logging.xml` for example), add a `RollingFileAppender` and set a `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` with `maxHistory` attribute for this appender.

Here an example of configuration:

```
    <appender name="ROLLINGFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/data/log/app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>/data/log/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%date\t\t%message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```